# How to interrupt process in Rstudio elegantly?

Tags: r, rstudio

Maybe it's because I'm too careless and often write the wrong code when dealing with big data. I tried to click the stop button(the red one in Rstudio), `ctrl + c`, `ctrl+z`, none of them can interrupt the process, and in the end I have to terminate the ```rsession`` and Rstudio in the terminal. Is ther anything else I can do? (I am using dplyr)

Answer (score 0):

You can press esc and wait the until job is cancelled

Comment: I would avoid the term "job", which should not be confounded with "jobs" option within RStudio.